# Create a mysql database using python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI for all database queries such as to create database, create table and insert record into table. But I am stuck in creating database as I want that all values like : host name, username, password and database name should be enter on gui window.

I tried this code

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import importlib
import os
import tkinter
import mysql.connector as msql
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd

root = Tk() 
root.geometry("500x500")
root.config(bg="light gray")

# declaring string variable 
host_var = StringVar()
user_var = StringVar()
pass_var = StringVar()
db_name = StringVar()


def Submit_db():
    host = host_var.get()
    user = user_var.get()
    pas = pass_var.get()
    db = db_name.get()
    
    print("Host name is"+host)
    print("user name is"+user)
    print("pass name is"+pas)
    print("db name is"+db)

    try:
        conn = msql.connect(host=host, user=user,  password=pas)
        if conn.is_connected():
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE "+ db)
            print(db+"database is created")
    except Error as e:
        print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
        
def create_db():
    root_db=Tk()
    root_db.geometry("350x350")
    
    Label(root_db,text="Host").grid(row=0,column=1)
    entry1= Entry(root_db,textvariable = host_var).grid(row=0,column=2)
    
    Label(root_db,text="User").grid(row=1,column=1)
    entry2 = Entry(root_db, textvariable = user_var).grid(row=1,column=2)
    
    Label(root_db,text="Password").grid(row=2,column=1)
    entry3 = Entry(root_db,textvariable= pass_var, show="*").grid(row=2,column=2)
    
    Label(root_db, text = "Database Name").grid(row=3,column=1)
    entry4 = Entry(root_db, textvariable= db_name).grid(row=3,column=2)
        
    Button(root_db, text= "Submit",command=Submit_db).grid(row=4,column=1)

    root_db.mainloop()


label1 = Label(root, text="Select your choice", font="bold")
label1.grid(row=0,column=1)

db_button = Button(root,text="Create database ",command=create_db)
db_button.grid(row=2,column=1)

table_botton = Button(root,text="Create table",font="bold").grid(row=2,column=2)

record_table=Button(root,text="Insert record",font="bold").grid(row=2,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

but it gives the error:

```
Host name is
user name is
pass name is
db name is
Error while connecting to MySQL 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It looks like it does not took the values from the entry window as print function returns nothing. I may be make mistake in *submit* button. But i have no idea how to connect them with each other to get it worked.

Comment: Your problem is not related to MySQL at all. You are having trouble getting the content of the UI fields.

Comment: yeah, i never said it is problem with sql. The problem is i don't know how to map these values with the sql creating database code. So, i can easly create a database in GUI.

Comment: It is because you have more than one instance of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` inside `create_db()`.

Comment: Oh i got it. Thanks....it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug.
You created ***create_database*** window that is **root_db** window using

***root = Tk()***
but ***Tk()*** can be used only 1 time. So the code is running but the variables you passed to the entry boxes are not working.

> Solution

Just change.

```
root_db = Tk()
```

to.

```
root_db = Toplevel(root)
```

It will work just try this.

**Hope you satisfied.**

**If yes, Tick mark the answer.**

Comment: what if i want to add one more window...should i use Toplevel() for that?